# "found version 4, expected 3" error in angular-froala-wysiwyg

Tags: angular

I use `angular-froala-wysiwyg` in my project.

My dependency configuration is:

```
{
    ...
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.7.2-1",
    ...
}
```

I have a dependenct, I am getting following error:

I started to receive following error. I wasn't getting this error before:

```
[ERROR] Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /Users/halil/Projects/abonelik-sihirbazi/src/abonelik-sihirbazi-2/business-services/node_modules/angular-froala-wysiwyg/editor/editor.directive.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
[ERROR]     at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (/Users/halil/Projects/abonelik-sihirbazi/src/abonelik-sihirbazi-2/business-services/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25590:34)
[ERROR]     at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (/Users/halil/Projects/abonelik-sihirbazi/src/abonelik-sihirbazi-2/business-services/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25378:46)
[ERROR]     at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolsOf (/Users/halil/Projects/abonelik-sihirbazi/src/abonelik-sihirbazi-2/business-services/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25359:14)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to Angular 5 release and latest version of `angular-froala-wysiwyg` has just been upgraded to Angular 5:

https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg/commits/master/package.json

The issue can be removed by downgrading `angular-froala-wysiwyg` to `2.7.2`:

```
{
    ...
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "2.7.2",
    ...
}
```

Comment: After changing version don't forget to run npm install once again, after npm install it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the following steps :

1. Open node modules from your angular folder.
2. Open the module which is giving version issue.
3. Open JSON file from that module
4. From that JSON file change the version to matching version.
   This will work for sure.